# If() vs. switch() - Same meaning but different behaviour?

Tags: if-statement, switch-statement

I would like to transform my if() conditional to switch() from this:

```
if($configuration['application'][$applicationName]['subdomain'] == true){
    foreach($configuration['language'] as $language){
        if($language['abbreviation'].'.'.$configuration['application'][$applicationName]['domain'] == $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']){
            $_SESSION['language'] = $language['abbreviation'];
        }
    }

    // If no subdomain detected and redirection is enabled, set default language
    if(!isset($_SESSION['language'])){
        $_SESSION['language'] = $configuration['application'][$applicationName]['language'];
    }
}
else {
    $_SESSION['language'] = $configuration['application'][$applicationName]['language'];
}
```

To this:

```
switch($configuration['application'][$applicationName]['subdomain']){
    case true:
        foreach($configuration['language'] as $language){
            if($language['abbreviation'].'.'.$configuration['application'][$applicationName]['domain'] == $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']){
                $_SESSION['language'] = $language['abbreviation'];
                break;
            }
        }
    default:
        $_SESSION['language'] = $configuration['application'][$applicationName]['language'];
        break;
}
```

I think it should be the same but it behaves differently ...
Switch is not working properly ...

Comment: What type of data is stored in `$configuration['application'][$applicationName]['subdomain']`? Is it boolean really, or there is some kind of string or integer, which is implicitly casted to bool in `if` version?

Comment: The specific programming (PHP?) you're using might be important here; also a description of exactly how it's behaving differently (could the `break` that's been added to the `foreach` loop be cuasing a change in your expected behavior?).

Comment: Well I am using php and $configuration['application'][$applicationName]['subdomain'] is boolean (it is read from .ini and typecasted to bool) ... And the thing is that the code in foreach is executed and default is also executed (break doesn't really break the switch?)

Answer (score 1):

I have reformatted your code, please check to make sure it is still correct.

As for your problem, to begin with you are missing a `break;` statement at the end of your `case true:` statement. (The `break` inside the `foreach` loop simply breaks out of that loop, not the `case` itself).

Comment: Well that is interesting, I thought that break should quit the switch (I think that this is the way it is done in c++) ... My intention was that if session is set in the true case it should quit the switch, otherwise it should continue to default case and then do the break...

Comment: I have just figured out that problem is the break inside foreach loop. It just does not work ... After the session is set in the if statement it continues to default and set the session again which is the problem.

Comment: @jzvelc: yep, that is why i mentioned you need another `break;` statement otherwise you will fall through to the next condition :)

Comment: Yeah but my point is that id the condition in foreach fails it should continue to default, otherwise not (or if config is set to false)